# Null reference exception while getting TFS build details

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am trying to get latest build details from my TFS server but the following line throws a null-reference exception.

```
ITestManagementTeamProject project = tms.GetTeamProject(proj.Name);
```

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.dll
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

This is the surrounding code

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(TfsTeamProjectCollection.GetFullyQualifiedUriForName("http://tfs2013-99-228:8080/tfs/si nhss"));
        tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
        VersionControlServer vcs = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
        ITestManagementService tms = tfs.GetService<ITestManagementService>();

        TeamProject[] teamProjects = vcs.GetAllTeamProjects(true);

        IBuildServer buildServer = (IBuildServer)tfs.GetService(typeof(IBuildServer));

        foreach (TeamProject proj in teamProjects)
        {
            IBuildDefinition[] defs = buildServer.QueryBuildDefinitions(proj.Name);

            System.Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Team Project: {0}", proj.Name));

            foreach (IBuildDefinition def in defs)
            {
                IBuildDetailSpec spec = buildServer.CreateBuildDetailSpec(proj.Name, def.Name);
                spec.MaxBuildsPerDefinition = 10;
                spec.QueryOrder = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildQueryOrder.FinishTimeDescending;
                spec.DefinitionSpec.Name = def.Name;
                spec.Status = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildStatus.All;

                IBuildQueryResult builds = buildServer.QueryBuilds(spec);

                if (builds.Builds.Length > 0)
                {
                    var buildDetail = builds.Builds[0];

                    ITestManagementTeamProject project = tms.GetTeamProject(proj.Name);

                    System.Console.WriteLine(string.Format("   {0} - {1} - {2}", def.Name, buildDetail.Status.ToString(), buildDetail.FinishTime));
                }
            }

            System.Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Trivial, but have you checked if `tms` is null?

Comment: tms is not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something wrong with your references. I tested your script, it works with the **Microsoft Team Foundation Server Extended Client** package installed.

1. Remove current references
2. Just try to install the NuGet package [Microsoft Team Foundation
       Server Extended Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/) by running following command in the
       Package Manager Console:

> PM> Install-Package Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient
>   -Version 15.112.1

3. Add below reference based on your script:

> using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;

Then try it again.

See below screenshot, it can get the project name correctly. 
[image]